# Click the button "in" or "on" the window - Technical Writing

Tags: word-choice, tech-writing

I'm writing instructions telling a user to click something in/on a computer window. I lean naturally towards "click the button in the window", but is it "click the button on the window"? (Note: this is referring to a small floating window within the larger browser window, if that makes a difference.)

I've seen it written both ways, so I'm unsure which is correct.

Comment: I can't give you a definitive, authoritative answer with supporting evidence, but I would strongly argue for ***in***; _on_ just seems to real-world-ish for a virtual object such as a window.  The button, however, is definitely (I'm assuming) contained _within_ the boundaries of the window, so ***in*** makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In the window** or **inside the window** is correct, since you are talking about a 2D shape:

> "click the button **in(side) the window**"

**On the window** would either indicate *on top of* or *above*, possibly even *on the surface of*, as in "There is a fly *on* the computer screen."

However, you can **click on a button** but this does not indicate where the button is, just where you must click:

> "**click on the button** in the window"

You may also have seen *on* used with a button to indicate it is in the active state, like a lightswitch that is "on". This is informal:

> "**toggle** the button **on**"
>
> "**switch on** the button"

Although an English teacher might prefer something more formal like:

> "click the button to **turn on** (a function)"